# Keeping cookie between transactions with Hyper

Tags: cookies, rust, session-cookies, hyper

I would like to be able to keep the cookie of a previous request for the next one :

```
let hyper_client = Client::new();
server_response  = hyper_client.request(Method::Get, url).headers(Headers::new()).send();
```

Assuming the code above compile, how could I retrieve the cookie of this session ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
match server_response.headers.get() {
   Some(&SetCookie(ref content)) => println!("Cookie: {:?}", content),
   _ => println!("No cookie found"),
}
```

Use the `Cookie` header for cookies sent *to* the server, and `SetCookie` for cookies sent *from* the server. I'm emphasising that because I only saw `Cookie` at first and it caught me out.

Also, notice that I am requesting the `SetCookie` header just by type inference from the pattern match. I could also have used the turbo-fish: `headers.get::<SetCookie>()`.

If you need to send the same cookie back the server, you can just clone the `SetCookie` values from the response back into a new `Cookie` header for the request:

```
let mut headers = Headers::new();
// if you received cookies in the server response then send the same ones back
if let Some(&SetCookie(ref content)) = server_response.headers.get() {
   headers.set(Cookie(content.clone()));
}

hyper_client.request(Method::Get, url)
    .headers(headers)
    .send();
```

Comment: Great I can retrieve it now !
But I can't reuse it... I tried to do `headers.set(content)` and... it doesn't work...
I think that I confuse `SetCookie` and `Cookie`, some help ?

Comment: I've added an example of sending the same cookie values back to the server

Comment: This answer seems to be outdated, since ``hyper::client::Client`` doesn't implemented a method which takes two parameters.

Comment: @PeterHall cookie functionality [was removed](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/issues/1536) from hyper, isn't it?